# Take the information inside a ListItem and send it to the next Activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am relatively new to the Eclipse & ADT plugin world, so any answers can you please explain what it's doing? It would be very helpful.

Basically, I have a list in one activity that will be populated by a HTTP request from a database API, this I am still working on. However, what I wish to know, is am I able to take the string in the ListItem and give that to a TextView in the next activity?

So for example, I tap 'Record 1' and it takes 'Record 1' and puts it inside a variable, then sends the user to the next screen, and inserts the variable into a TextView. Is this possible?

Thank you.

Comment: None of this seems impossible, it all comes in how your architect your listview, and the data behind it.

Comment: override onitemclick listener of listview from there you can get text with the help of view which you get in that method , from there start new activity by putting extra data(view's text) in intent so in new activity you can fetch that data from intent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get what you want from the adapter, then put that into the Intent that starts the new activity:

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String string = parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, nextActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("text", string);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

In the new Activity you then get the Intent that started the new Activity and get the String you put into it:

```
String data = getIntent().getStringExtra("text");
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement the `setOnItemClickListener()` for the listItem  where you will capture the listItem clicked and the `String` you require and then using `intent.putExtra(String id, STRING_VALUE)` you can pass your string to the next activity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

You can send information to another activity using `Extra`. See this code below:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, NoteEdit.class);
i.putExtra(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id);
startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
```

You use `putExtra` to put your data do you want to send to the activity. In the example `NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID` is the name you give to access the data and `id` is the data itself.

And, this is how you can get the data from the activity:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
mRowId = (extras == null) ? null : extras.getLong(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);
```