# Is it possible to change screen, and send text (putExtra), by chosing a list item, and how?

Tags: android, string, list, listview, android-intent

I'm a working on a recipe app, and I was wondering if you can use list items to change screen, send text to next activity, just like you would using a button,

if its possible then how do i do it?

Comment: yes it is very possible, check out my answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084581/take-the-information-inside-a-listitem-and-send-it-to-the-next-activity/11084736#11084736

Comment: actually i was just wandering how to make each item do something different eg. send different text, as when i implemented your answer into my code, every item did the same thing - how do i make each item do something different?

Comment: It all depends on what the adapter returns with getItem(), you can change it so it returns the text of the item in the list, or anything else for that matter. You can also create your own methods in the adapter that you can call instead: YourObject object = ((YourAdapterClass)parent.getAdapter()).yourMethod(position); - Returns the YourObject from the position in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
      // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          Intent intent = new Intent(CURRENT_ACTIVITY.this*, NEW_ACTIVITY.class);
          intent.putExtra("keyName", "somevalue");
          startActivity(intent);
    }
  });
```

in Activity B

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
if(extras !=null)
{
String value = extras.getString("keyName");
}
```